# Escape unicode symbols in NetBeans-Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

I have problems with Unicode(UTF-8) and Russians symbols. It gives me this message:

```
Текущий предмет: [["\u041E\u0431\u044A\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043D\u043E-\u043E\u0440\u0438\u0435\u043D\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043E\u0432\u0430\u043D\u043D\u043E\u0435 \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043C\u043C\u0438\u0440\u043E\u0432\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0435"]]
ФИО преподавателя: [["\u041B\u0443\u043D\u0435\u0432\u0430 \u0415.\u0415."]]
```

Plus how can i check that i've got no matches by using regex?

IDE: NetBeans 7.3

My attempts to solve this problem:

1. using magic lines (encoding: utf-8) in the beginning of script
2. file = File.new("rasp.txt","w:UTF-8")

My Code:

```
#!/bin/env ruby          #change encoding by using magic
# encoding: utf-8

#libs
require "open-uri"
# To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

site_content = open("http://rasp.tpu.ru/view.php?for=10-116+%2F%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%2F&weekType=1").read
file = File.new("rasp.txt","w:UTF-8")
#поиск названия текущего предмета
search_subjname = site_content.scan(/<td class="current-day current-time">.*title="([^>]*)"/)
#поиск ФИО преподавателя
search_name = site_content.scan(/<td class="current-day current-time">.*title="[^>]*".*\s*<div.*\s*<a.*>(.*)</)

puts search_subjname
puts search_name
#
#
#Adding a subject
file.write("Текущий предмет: ")
unless search_subjname.empty?
  if search_subjname.first.empty?
    file.write("Сейчас пар в этой аудитории нет")
  else
    file.write(search_subjname)
  end
end

#Adding FIO to file
file.write("\nФИО преподавателя: ")
unless search_name.empty?
  if search_name.first.empty?
    file.write("Преподаватель отсутствует")
  else
    file.write(search_name)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest to use `nokogiri` in searching in context of page, not regex.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it's my lab work and i have to use only regex :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ? https://github.com/singlebrook/utf8-cleaner

It's a good gem for removes invalid UTF-8 characters from the environment